# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #38:

Tags: android, kotlin

Custom class ::

```
class TimerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    var totalDays: Int = 0
    var daysLeft: Int = 0

    
    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.view_timer_progress_bar,this)
        circularProgressbar.progress = 28

    }
```

}

view_timer_progress_bar

```
    <TimerView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar_timer_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_64"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_64"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
    
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_142"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_142"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/timer_circular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressbar_timer_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progressbar_timer_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/progressbar_timer_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressbar_timer_view"
            tools:max="100"
            tools:progress="50"
            tools:secondaryProgress="100" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time_days"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_14"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:text="28\ndays"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             />
    
    </TimerView>
```

I am trying this TimerView custom view include in another layout like below

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_timer_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
        <include layout="@layout/widget_timer_progress_bar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In  class view, I initialize like this

```
private lateinit var timerView: TimerView

    private lateinit var timerView: TimerView
    onCreateView(){
     timerView = contentView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_timer_view)
    }
```

I am getting above binary inflate exception. I want to create a custom view so that I can use any place as with dynamic value with a different view I can reuse this  please suggest and help me what I am doing wrong

```
Stack trace:: <P>paste.ofcode.org/34qQkj2dFnEMBpak8HdRTja</p>
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace too. Anyway, looks like you have infinite recursion with the custom view inner layout containing the custom view itself.

Comment: Process: com.myapp.mobile.titan.prodtest.debug, PID: 23774
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class 
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class widget.TimerView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: I am unable to add a link here so I can not post full

Comment: you need to edit your post to include the stacktrace

Comment: like @laalto says though, you have a recursion problem - your ``TimerView`` custom view inflates a layout which contains another ``TimerView``. You need a layout with what's *inside* the ``TimerView``, then you can just add a ``TimerView`` element to the layout that wants to use it, same as you would for a ``TextView`` or anything else

Comment: can you suggest code wise just as an example i tried  Timer view as the main layout then also it's not working

Comment: In that stacktrace pastebin, there's `Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero at widget.TimerView.getDegreesForDay(TimerView.kt:73)`

Comment: That seems like a circular reference, your custom view class is trying to inflate a layout that contains the custom view

Comment: OK let me check